# I have an object with repeated values, I need to get the repeated values and insert them inside the parent object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
.done(function(data){
    var items = data.d.results;
    var programas = new Object();
    var titleProgramaId = "";
    var titleProgramaIdAtual = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        titleProgramaIdAtual = items[i].Concessao.Title+"-"+items[i].ConcessaoId;           
        if(titleProgramaIdAtual != titleProgramaId){
            programas[i] = {"Title":items[i].Concessao.Title,"Ano":items[i].Concessao.AnoPrograma,"Id":items[i].ConcessaoId};
            titleProgramaId = titleProgramaIdAtual;
        }
    }
    console.log(programas);
    console.log(items);



 {0: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}, 9: {…}}
0: {Title: "Programa 1", Ano: "2015", Id: 3}
4: {Title: "Programa 2", Ano: "2015", Id: 8}
5: {Title: "Programa 2", Ano: "2016", Id: 4}
7: {Title: "Programa 3", Ano: "2017", Id: 5}
8: {Title: "Programa 1", Ano: "2018", Id: 9}
9: {Title: "Programa 4", Ano: "2018", Id: 6}
```

I need to get the repeated values ​​from the ID object and create a new array of objects inside it. Someone to help me?

Comment: @MatheusAraujo repeated based on what? title or Ano?

Comment: @NinjaJami based on ID from zero to 4 all are Id 3, I want to group them together

Answer (score 0):

This function will group by **Id**

```
 getDuplicatedArray(inputArray) {
    var result= inputArray.reduce(function (acc, item) {
      let key = (item['Id']);
      (acc[key] ? acc[key] : (acc[key] = null || [])).push(item);
      return acc;
    }, {});
    return result
  }
```

Sample Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-reduce-duplicate?file=index.js

Comment: In that case what would the complete code be like along with mine that I put up?

Comment: @MatheusAraujo updated with a demo. I hope that's something you are looking for

Comment: That would be fine, but the time I play for my code is giving trouble. inputArray.reduce is not a function. I implemented this way: function getDuplicatedArray(inputArray) {
    var outObject = inputArray.reduce(function (acc, item) {
      let key = (item['Id']);
      (acc[key] ? acc[key] : (acc[key] = null || [])).push(item);
      return acc;
    }, {});
    return outObject
  }   
  var repeatedElements = getDuplicatedArray(programas); Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @MatheusAraujo it's because you are applying reduce function on the top of an object like { {},{}} , it should be [{},{}]

Comment: @MatheusAraujo pass results instead of programas, because you are creating arrays on the top of programas object.

Comment: @MatheusAraujo If it;s helps please mark it as answer or upvote

Comment: It would only lack one thing, it would need to be in ascending order of Ano. So it is changing and leaving in ascending order of Id

Comment: In the first position of the parent objects I need to bring the first element of the child elements